# What does InterSystems.Data.CacheClient.dll use under ADO.NET to connect to a Cache database?

Tags: .net, intersystems-cache, intersystems

Here's an [example](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBMP_connect):

Anyone know?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Under the covers it's using the c-callin interface. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @O.O Have you compared performance of ODBC vs. the CacheClient managed provider?  Did one outperform the other?  We currently use ODBC but now looking at the provider.

Comment: @SirCrispalot - Have not compared, but it's written in all managed code so it's your best bet for .NET applications.  I have not noticed any drawbacks as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly sure it uses a TCP-based protocol to communicate with the back end Cache server, and that the protocol is proprietary (as I would assume most such wire protocols eventually are).

As with kazamatzuri, I am not sure what the question is really getting at.

Comment: I just needed to make sure it wasn't wrapping up some sort of ODBC connection.